# How to change the version number of a revision in RCS

Tags: version-control, rcs

Suppose a file has 4 revisions (1.1 to 1.4). I deleted revisions 1.2 and 1.3 using `rcs -o1.2:1.3 myfile.txt`. Now I want to change revision number 1.4 to become revision number 1.2. How do I do this using RCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to recreate the archive-file.  rcs will allow you to *increase* the revision number with a new check-in, but won't allow you to *decrease* it.